# Display multi-select box choices in a bullet list

Tags: php, forms, buddypress

I have a form that includes a multi-select box.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <select name="countries[]" size="5" multiple="true">
  <option value="bolivia">Bolivia</option>
  <option value="canada">Canada</option>
  <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
  <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
  <option value="united states">United States</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" size="5"></p>
</form>
```

The code is displayed with the following PHP code:

```
<?php bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' ); ?>
```

How do I separate the results into a bullet list?

Comment: Make a `var_dump()` of the result of `bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' )`, and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment below:

> This code displays the members selections but only as a comma
>   separated list: `<?php bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' ); ?>`

```
// $countries_csl should contain something like 'hufflepuff, hogwarts, heaven, hell'
$contries_csl = bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' );
// convert the comma seperated list (csl) into an array by using explode( [delimiter], [string] )
$countries = explode( ',', $countries_csl );

// check if the string to array conversion was successfull
if ( is_array( $countries ) && ! empty( $countries ) ) {
    // adjust the html to your needs (add some css classes or something else)
    echo '<ul>';

    // walk over the array and print out a li-item for each array element
    foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
        // to be sure that every country starts with an UpperCase letter, use ucfirst()
        printf( '<li>%s</li>', ucfirst( $country ) );
    }

    // do not forget to close the list
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

You have a comma seperated list, you need a bullets list. Just convert the comma seperated list into an array and walk over it to generate a bullets list.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of detail. I'm not very proficient at PHP so not sure what information I need to provide. Anyway, I'm trying to display the results of a multi-select box from the BuddyPress profile registration page on to a single members page in a bullet list format. This code displays the members selections but only as a comma separated list: 

     <?php bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Countries' ); ?>

Let me know what else I need to provide. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please do not forget to accept the answer if it works, so other can see if it is the right soution or not.

Comment: @Ralf912 - I believe you need to use  bp_get_member_profile_data(...) instead because he needs to get the list and then manipulate per your code.  bp_member_profile_data(...) will echo the list.

Comment: @shanebp Ah thanks. I'm not so experienced with bbpress and take the code from his comment.